# Javascript Mobile sites

Tags: javascript, css

I am using the following javascript to detect whether the site is viewed on a mobile device it works perfectly as a redirect (see example 1);

However, is it possible to amend it to so it amends the font size of an element or class (the original font-size is contained within an external style sheet) when the same condition is satisfied, that being a iDevice is detected.

```
 //original code: (Javascript)

 // iDevice
var iDevice = {

// Android
Android: function() {
return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
},

// Blackberry
BlackBerry: function() {
return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
},

// Apple
iOS: function() {
return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
},

// Opera Browser
Opera: function() {
return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
},

// Windows Mobile
Windows: function() {
return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
},

// Function: (iDevice)
any: function(){
return (iDevice.Android() || iDevice.BlackBerry() || iDevice.iOS() || iDevice.Opera() || iDevice.Windows());
    }
};


<!-- Working HTML -->

{
if( iDevice.any() )
window.location = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would be to modify the JavaScript so that it adds one or more custom classes to the 'body' element in your HTML based on the device agent. Then, in your CSS, you could do something like this:

```
.header {
    /* default font size */
}

.android .header,
.iphone .header
.mobile .header {
    /* custom font size */
}
```

However, a better solution might be to [forgo user agent detection](https://css-tricks.com/browser-detection-is-bad/) and instead use [media queries](http://learnlayout.com/media-queries.html) to make your website [responsive](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/) based on the actual width of the device the user is using to view your website.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work on any device that you haven't explicitly enumerated. For example, why don't you support [Firefox OS](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/os/2.0/)?

Of course you can try to enumerate every single mobile device ever produced (and keep doing that to keep your code working for new devices) and change the font size for the detected mobile devices (that you know about) but it would be much better to use [**responsive web design**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) for things like that.

You can use a framework like:

- [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)
- [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)

or many others, or to use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) yourself if you don't want to use those frameworks.

See: [Media Queries for Standard Devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) on CSS-Tricks.